# Inline svg sprite image making multiple calls

Tags: html, angular, svg, sprite

I am using svg sprite in my application. The browser is making multiple calls when loading the page. Please let me know where i am doing wrong.

```
<icon-component>

    `<svg
        class="aiq-icon-container"
        [attr.disabled]="disabled"
        [style.width.px]="sizeMap[size] ? sizeMap[size] : sizeMap[defaultSize]"
        [style.height.px]="sizeMap[size] ? sizeMap[size] : sizeMap[defaultSize]">
        <use [attr.xlink:href]="'assets/svg/sprite.svg#' + name"></use>
      </svg>`
    </icon-component>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

These calls are made again and again on the page refresh as you done a filter for sprite image. so that's why you are seeing multiple calls for the sprite.svg

Comment: Thanks Hitesh , How can I  avoid avoid such multiple calls ?

Comment: If it only making multiple calls when the page is refreshed then there is an issue.  By my understanding the multiple calls where made on multiple times page reload or refreshed. Would you please check again by clearing the  network by clicking on the cancel icon besides the red button on the screen and do a page refresh again and check if the call is made one then it is ok